# Crystal oscillator producing straight line only

Tags: transistors, capacitor, resistors, oscillator, crystal

I have replicated a crystal oscillator circuit from internet, but the output waveform is a pure DC rather than the expected sine wave. Below are my circuit diagram and the simulation output from Multisim.

[image]

[image]

Kindly help me figure out if there is something wrong with this circuit and what can be done to resolve this.

Comment: Try doing something to "kick" your oscillator on. Like start V1 at 0 V and ramp it to 9 V after the start of the simulation.

Comment: Your circuit seems OK at first glance. It likely just needs a "kick" to get started.

Comment: I got it. It's producing oscillations. How silly it was. However it has a high DC bias component. Can you tell me how to make the oscillations range from -x to + x rather than from +a to +a+2x.

Comment: Just capacitively couple the output (series C, resistor to GND) to get rid of the bias.

Comment: If 27MHz crystal oscillator, C2 & C3 are too big, especially C2. Rough guess: try C2=27pf, C3=56pf. You may have to play with C1 value to get the frequency exact. Hope you get "parallel-resonant" crystal (not series). Also, be aware that at this frequency, some crystals are 3rd harmonic, some are fundamental. A 3rd-harmonic crystal *might* want to oscillate at 9 MHz rather than 27MHz.

Comment: The oscilloscope is not grounded.

Comment: That doesn't matter @Chu

Answer (score 2):

Wrong transistor for 3MHz .. 2N5088  has hFE of 350 nom but only 50MHz GBW nom. thus current gain is only 16 @ 3MHz

Did you want to try a CMOS or TTL XO design?

Comment: Hi. My goal is actually 27 MHz. I didn't know that so just placed any random.

Comment: series or parallel?

Comment: whatever works at lower cost. I am an aspirant manufacturer, I don't have much of domain knowledge though.

Comment: Better off using https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/ECS/ECS-3225S33-270-FN-TR?qs=sGAEpiMZZMt8zWNA7msRCurZdFB2kkrnIdkLwjJNGNPthrBtXYWaug%3D%3D

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. However, i see that it would greatly impact the margins as res, cap etc will cost about a tenth of that

Comment: So revise question to specify exactly what you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91831/discussion-between-its-a-trap-and-sunnyskyguy-ee75).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have found a transistor with suitable Ft, R1 is too small relative to R2; they should be more egual. At Fo , hfe should be more than C3/C2 but not excessively so.